# How to plot pseudo-3d bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

I'd like to prepare some statistics for my boss. The flat style of matplotlib bar chart would make them look cheap for those used to Excel charts, although for clarity, using styles like this probably should be avoided.

I'm not that far away, but I don't get how to give the right thickness of the bars:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

row = [0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 4, 16, 2, 0, 4, 4, 12, 26]
length = len(row)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = np.arange(length)
y = np.zeros(14)
z = np.array(row)
width = 0.8
ax.bar3d(x, y, [0]*length, 0.5, 0.001, z)
ax.set_xticks(x + width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(titles[2:], rotation=90)
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_zlabel('count')
plt.show()
```

Result:[image: Result]

Comment: What have you tried?  There was a question about cylinders for bars recently.  Curious comparison to Excel though, I have the exact opposite reaction.

Comment: Maybe you can use the steps outlined on [this website](http://www.jkwchui.com/2010/03/3d-bar-histogram-in-python/) or [this updated/additional information](http://www.jkwchui.com/2010/04/3d-histogram-in-python-2/)

Comment: Schorsch, thanks, I've been there but the code gets very brokenly displayed. :(

Comment: Web convinces me using this is no good idea after all: For example github.com/propublica/guides/blob/master/news-apps.md "Avoid 3-D charts at all costs."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thickness of the bars are set by the `dx, dy` arguments in `ax.bar3d` for which you have the values `0.5, 0.001`. The issue, as I'm sure you noticed is that changing `dy` will change the length of the bar (in your case the untitled axis), but matplotlib helpfully rescales the y axis so the data fills it. This makes it look strange (I am assuming this is the problem, sorry if it isn't).

To remedy this you could  set the y limits using `ax.set_ylim(0, 0.002)` (basically your y values go from 0->0.001). If you change either `dy` or the value of y given to `bar3d` which is currently 0, then you will need to update the limits accordingly.

Example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

row = [0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 4, 16, 2, 0, 4, 4, 12, 26]
length = len(row)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(range(length), [0]*length, [0]*length, 0.5, 0.001, row)

ax.set_ylim(-0.005, 0.005)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd have to put a lot of guesswork into that. Making the y ticks practically invisible didn't help me, either. ;)